# Unable to access a Private Array

Tags: arrays, c++11, private-members

I'm having difficulty accessing an array of strings.  It is declared as a private array and filled in the constructor for the class.   I have a Get function defined.  The problem is when I call this function at compile time I get an error that I cannot access private member declared in class.  I'm just getting back into coding just for the yuks, as such I'm at a stage pre-pointers and pre-vectors so I'm trying to avoid situations that would force their use.

Words.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class Words {
    Words();

    public:
        std::string GetNewWord(int);

    private:
         std::string WordList[23] = {};
};
```

Words.cpp  - The Array is completely filled but shortened here

```
#include "Words.h"

Words::Words(){
    WordList[0] = "omega";
    WordList[1] = "minors";
    WordList[2] = "stigma";
    WordList[3] = "glamor";
    WordList[4] = "savior";
    WordList[5] = "disarm";
    WordList[6] = "isogram";
    .
    .
    .
    ;
}

std::string Words::GetNewWord(int choice)
    {
        return WordList[choice];
    }
```

main.cpp  - contains an infinite loop so i could quickly test if the array was populated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Words.h"

Words word;

int main() {

    do {
        std::cout << "choice: ";
        int choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        std::cout << "\n" << word.GetNewWord(choice) << "\n";

    } while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor is private, as all members of a class are by default. Simply move it to the public section.

Comment: What is the difference between having a private int or some other type vs. an array.  Most texts say that any static variables or data that belongs to the class are tagged private either by default or by using the private tag and then define get/set methods to access them.  Your advice solves the problem but creates a new question about what is the proper way to use class defined array vs other class defined data.

Comment: There is no difference at all. Your problem has nothing to do with the member beeing an array or with the getter method.  The constructor of your class was private and so not accessible.  Thats what the  compiler complained about.